# Render apex:tabPanel as a pdf using VF pages

Tags: visualforce, pdf, tabpanel

I am trying to render a vf page as a pdf. The page contains tab panels, but when it is rendered as pdf, the tabs are not clickable. Only the active tab shows and I am unable to switch to other tabs. The page is working correctly if I am rendering as HTML.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualforce pages rendered as PDF do not include any JavaScript and are not interactive. This simply isn't possible with the renderer used to create PDFs (Flying Saucer).